# Почему второй <span> переносится на новую строку?

Tags: html, css

Цель в том, чтобы строка была на подобии:
"1.1 NewSectionnnnnnnnnnn-
nnn"
Но как бы я не игрался c word-wrap и overflow-wrap - слово почему-то переносится.
Как бы достигнуть чтобы заголовок во втором span не переносился с начала, а перенос был остуществлён на последних буквах которые выходят за область блока?

**Html:**

```
<span class="secno">
      <xsl:number level="multiple"
        count="topic[normalize-space(title) != '']"
        format="1."/>
    </span>
    <span class="content">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </span>
```

**Css:**

```
body {
    counter-reset: example figure issue;
    /* Layout */    
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    /* Typography */
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Calibri light;
    font-size: 8pt;
    widows: 2;
    orphans: 2;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;

    /* Colors */
    color: black;   
}

body #toc {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0; 
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 90mm;
        text-decoration: none;
        overflow: auto;
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        padding: 0 0 0 3mm;
        background-color: #5e5b5b;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    body #toc a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    body #toc ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    body #toc li.chapter-title{
        margin-top: 6mm;
    }
    
    body #toc li.chapter-title>a{
        /*color: #fdc300;*/
        color: #e8e8e6;
        font-family: Calibri light;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        word-wrap: break-word,
    }
    
    body #toc li.section-title>a{
        padding-left: 3mm;
        color: #e8e8e6;
        font-family: Calibri light;
        font-size: 12pt;    
        word-wrap: break-word,  
    }
    
    body #toc li.topic-title>a{
        padding-left: 3mm;
        color: #e8e8e6;
        font-family: Calibri light;
        font-size: 10pt;
        word-wrap: break-word,
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оберните эти `span` `в div` и задайте ему минимальную фиксированную ширину

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="secno">
    <xsl:number level="multiple" count="topic[normalize-space(title) != '']" format="1."/>
  </span>
  <span class="content">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

в стилях:

```
.wrapper {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```